# Select records from a SQL Server database using geography and distance

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sqlgeography

I am using the SQL Server geography datatype to store the location of records in my database.
I would like to select all records within a given distance of a given location:

```
DECLARE @location AS geography = geography::Point(@latitude, @longitude, 4326)
DECLARE @distance AS INT = 10000

SELECT * 
FROM records
WHERE records.location.STDistance(@location) <= @distance
```

With a couple of dozen records in my test database this runs pretty quickly and I don't have any issues, but I know that WHERE clause is running STDistance against all records in my database, and once I have thousands of records, it's going to slow to a crawl.

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe create some sort of region and first select data in neighboring regions?

Comment: You can do a series of bounding boxes to narrow down the range of lat/longs that are checked in the ST_Distance function...however, I'd recommend letting MIcrosoft do it.  DO a google for MSSQL spatial indexing

Comment: [Spatial Indexes Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895265.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most definitely want to set up a spatial index as @Twelfth recommends. You also want to do your search on a range, not distance to take better advantage of the spatial index.

```
DECLARE @location AS geography = geography::Point(@latitude, @longitude, 4326)
DECLARE @distance AS INT = 10000
DECLARE @range AS geography = @location.STBuffer(@distance)

SELECT * 
FROM records
WHERE records.location.STIntersects(@Range) = 1
```